# How can I find downloaded files from email when connected to my computer?

Tags: email, attachments

I downloaded a PDF file from GMail

When I connected my phone to my Computer, I cannot find the file.

Where can I find files downloaded from GMail?

Comment: give more details like phone model and OS version

Answer (score 2):

You have downloaded the file but,you haven't saved it yet.That's the reason why you are not able to see it when you are connect your phone with your laptop.
All you need to do is go to your email and press and hold till the pop up appear,then select the save option.After that you will be able to see that file.